# Rigid Body stops at the upper surface of a hollow cube

Tags: modeling, modifiers, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

[image]I am very new to blender and so forgive me if the question sounds vague. I am trying to create a scenario where I have a hollow bin with cloth on its edges and drop some objects into it (In Blender 2.8). I created the hollow bin by subdividing the default cube and deleting the upper face. later, I added a few planes with cloth simulations which will collide with the cube and rest on it. I have then animated the objects to fall into the cube at a frame where the clothes have settled in. In order to support the collision between the cloth and the active rigid body, I have added passive rigid body properties to the cloth. When I run the simulation, The active rigid body objects do not fall in the cube. Instead, they stop just above the cube and stay there until the simulation ends. I have made all the collision shapes as mesh.
Can someone please help me with the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly your bin needs solid walls and floor (using the Solidify modifier and recalculate outside normals) rather than a cube with upper face removed.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is, the cloth needs to be active if it is going to be deformed in anyway during your simulation.
The second thing is the result of the collision distance being too high. Finding and reducing that will decrease how far above the cloth the falling objects are when the collision is detected.......

Comment: Hi Jarrett. Thank you for the response. The said settings are already available. The cloth is always active and the margin of collision is the smallest value possible (0.001). I have added an image to show how the cloth simulation is working. This behaviour is as expected. The problem is, when I try to add an object (like another cube or some .stl files) and make it an active rigid body, it doesn't fall into the hollow bin and stops at the surface.